# When I run msxsl.exe on my DBML file, it introduces carriage returns that mess up the final SQLMetal.exe step

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2019, dbml, msxsl

I just upgraded from VS 2015 to VS 2019 (and Windows 7 to Windows 10).  My project is using SQLMetal.exe and msxsl.exe **in a batch file** to create and modify the DBML in three steps:

1. Generate the DataModel.dbml file with SQLMetal.exe.
2. Add database transforms with msxsl.exe.
3. Generate the DataModel.cs file with SQLMetal.exe.

When I ran this in the new environment, it gave me a strange error:

```
DataModel.dbml(0) : Error: DBML1112: Element 'Column" must be empty, but contains a node of type Whitespace named ''.
```

After much trial and error, I realized that the msxls.exe (that I just downloaded) adds carriage returns before the closing column and association tags in the DBML file.  This seems to be what is causing the error on the final SQLMetal.exe step.

```
<Column Name="SortOrder" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false">
</Column>
```

I can actually open the DataModel.dbml file after step 2 and replace all on "\r\n < /Column>" to "< /Column>" and "\r\n< /Assocation>" to "< /Association>", and then Step 3 seems to work.  Obviously, I don't want to have to do this every time, though.

**So, what do I need to do to run msxsl.exe and not have it add the carriage returns before the closing Column and Association tags?**

The msxls command is as follows:

```
"C:\VSBuild\msxsl.exe" "%~dp0DataModel.dbml" "%~dp0ModifyDbml.xslt" -o "%~dp0DataModel.dbml"
```

Does the version of msxsl matter?

Comment: Since you've not shown us your `msxsl` command, we're guessing - but perhaps adding the `-xw ` option may assist.

Comment: @Magoo I added the command above.  Appending "-xw" on it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I'll freely admit to being as far from an expert with `msxsl` as it is possible to be, but I'd try three things : First, restore the older version of `msxsl` from your copious backups; second, reduce the name `sortorder` to a shorter string and if neither of these work, then use a utility like `sed` or `(g)awk` to dispose of the unwanted newline.